# Find two subgroups which direct product is a group

Tags: group-theory

Let $G=\mathbb {D_6} = \{e, x, x^2 , …, x^5, y, xy, …, x^4y, x^5y \}$ show $G$ is a direct product of it's two subgroups (non trivial).

I'm not sure if I can take two subgroups $A=\{e, x, x^2, x^3, x^4, x^5 \}$ and $B=\{e, y \}$ then $A \times B=\mathbb {D_6}$ ? I'm not sure because I've seen only direct products from $A,B$ where A, B have the same number of elements and don't know if $\{a\} \times \{b,c \} =\{ab, ac \}$ ?

Comment: Perhaps a partial source of confusion here is that, strictly speaking, we're looking for $A, B$ such that $A \times B \cong \Bbb D_6$. We cannot have $A \times B = \Bbb D_6$, as elements of $A \times B$ are ordered pairs of elements of subgroups of $\Bbb D_6$. So, we really need to pick appropriate subgroups $A, B \leq \Bbb D_6$ and give an isomorphism $\phi: A \times B \to \Bbb D_6$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** The order of $\Bbb D_6$ is $12$, so if it is isomorphic to a direct product of nontrivial subgroups $A, B$, those groups must have orders $2$ and $6$, or orders $3$ and $4$. All groups of orders $3$ and $4$ are abelian and hence so are their direct products, but $\Bbb D_6$ is nonabelian, so $A, B$ have orders $2$ and $6$. There is only one nonabelian group of order $6$, so we can assume $A \cong \Bbb Z_2$ and $B \cong S_3$.

Comment: Why we assume that $A \cong \Bbb Z_2$ and $B \cong S_3$ ? I mean why we don't pick particular subgroups of $D_6$ ? and can you say how looks direct product when $A,B$ have different cardinality ?

Comment: We know from the answer that one of $A$ and $B$ has order $2$ and the other has order $6$, and by relabeling we may as well assume that $\# A = 2$ and $\# B = 6$. Up to isomorphism there is only one group of order $2$, so $A \cong \Bbb Z_2$. There are two groups of order $6$, namely $\Bbb Z_6$ and $S_3$, but $\Bbb Z_6$ is abelian, so it cannot be isomorphic to $B$ (otherwise, $\Bbb D_6$ would be isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_2 \times \Bbb Z_6$, and so would be abelian). Thus, $B \cong S_6$.

Comment: As the problem is framed, we *do* want to pick subgroups $A, B$ of $\Bbb D_6$---the hint tells us what those subgroups must look like.

Comment: so the subgroups are $A = \{e, y  \} $ and $B= \{e, x^2, x^4, xy, x^3y, x^5y \} $ ?

Comment: In that case, what is your isomorphism $\phi: A \times B \to \Bbb D_6$?

Comment: for $a \in A \ \ b \in B$ we have $f (a \cdot b)=a \cdot b $ ?

Comment: The domain of $\phi$ consists of ordered pairs, so we ought to write something like $\phi(a, b) := ab$. Can you check whether this is an isomorphism?

Comment: we can see that if $(a,b) \neq (c,d)$ then $ab \neq cd $ and every element in $D_6$ is of form $x^iy^j$ where $i=0,1,…,4 \ \ j=0,1$ and have as well for every $p \in D_6$ we can take such $a,b$ so $f(a,b) = p$ but I don't know how write it but it's easy to see

Comment: is it ok ? since I'm not 100% sure

Comment: This shows that $\phi$ is bijective, but not that it preserves the group structure, i.e., that it is an isomorphism. We must show that $\phi((a, b) \cdot (c, d)) = \phi(a, b) \cdot \phi(c, d)$, where $\cdot$ is used to denote both of the group operations.